# Cannot use `?` operator for functions that return Result<(), error>

Tags: rust

Given this example:

```
fn function() -> Result<(), &'static str> {
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
   function()?; // Compile error
}
```

I get the error: `cannot use the ? operator in a function that returns ()`.

Why can't I use the `?` operator for such functions? Is there syntactic sugar to avoid using a `match` statement?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What do you want to happen if `function()` returns an `Err` result? You can’t use `try!`/`?` because it causes the containing function to return the same `Err`, but `main()` can’t return an `Err` (it returns `()`, not `Result<…>`). If you want to panic, you can use [`unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap):

```
function().unwrap();
```

If you want to ignore errors, discard the result:

```
let _ = function();
```

Comment: So in other words, the only reason the above code fails is because the `?` operator is in `main`, and `main` can't return a value, which `?` tries to do?

Comment: Note that since 1.26 (May 2018), Rust now allows `main` to return a `Result`

Comment: A better way to discard a `Result` is to go `function().ok();`: converts `Result` to `Option`, which the compiler won't complain about not handling.

Comment: @mikerodent: Why is that better? This is exactly what `let _ =` is for; it’s what other readers will recognize. `.ok()` looks like a mistake (I would assume someone meant to write `.unwrap()`, since `.ok()` looks like “assert OK”).

Comment: Matter of opinion then. I think `let _ = ...` looks silly, inelegant and like a mistake.

Comment: @mikerodent: I’m not sure if you’re aware/this changes your opinion on it, but unlike e.g. Python or JavaScript, `_` is actual pattern syntax in Rust that matches any value and discards it. It’s not a hack variable name, and it’s idiomatic.

Comment: I'm a newb to Rust and to the Rust culture. I've studied The Book about 1 and a half times, so yes I'd got that idea about underscore. I defer to your (much) greater knowledge of the culture and the language, but I don't see at this point that using syntax which shows you are assigning something to no purpose is particularly desirable...

Comment: Actually I'm curious now about what the compiler does, particularly for a release: I've read that Rust's compiler does some very powerful optimisation (and in fact I've experienced this quite dramatically, comparing speeds after use of `--release` with not using it). So I'm wondering when you have `let _ = ...` whether the compiler on `--release` doesn't bother in fact assigning anything at all. So in many ways it might be better to disable that warning of "should be assigned". Not that it really matters!

Comment: ... and in fact not converting to an `Option` might save on a few instructions. Although I bet the compiler is also able to spot that that operation is equally pointless and omit it.

Comment: @mikerodent: Right, the compiler won’t emit extra instructions (to assign or convert or…) no matter what you do. The explicit discarding of a `Result` this way is a hint to the reader, not the compiler, pointing out the atypical choice to ignore it.

Answer (score 7):

Your `main` function does not return a `Result`.  You need to do something with the error case.  Probably something like `function().expect("oh no! function() failed!!");`, which will cause a panic and error exit in the unlikely event `function()` fails.  `expect()` turns a `Result<A,B>` into an `A` on success, and panics displaying a combination of your error message and the `B` on failure.

Or you could use `Result::unwrap()` which works similarly without adding an error message of your own, just using the error value of the `Result`.

Comment: `fn main() -> Result<(), String> { function()?; Ok(()) }`