# cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `()`

Tags: rust, reqwest

I am very new to rust and I want to write a script to scrape a page and pull all the links from it with their titles. I have failed to even make the get request. :(

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Started!");
    let body = reqwest::get("https://news.ycombinator.com")
    .await?
    .text()
    .await?;

    println!("body = {:?}", body);
}
```

I am clearly not returning anything however I am confused with the syntax can someone explain the ? operator and also help me fix this issue.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/#the-question-mark-operator-

Comment: https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/07_workarounds/03_err_in_async_blocks.html

Comment: Also see: [Strange error: cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225498/strange-error-cannot-use-the-operator-in-a-function-that-returns) and [Cannot use `?` operator for functions that return Result<(), error>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015600/cannot-use-operator-for-functions-that-return-result-error) for more answers.

Answer (score 15):

The question mark operator can only be used inside functions that return a `std::Result`. Roughly speaking, you can think of `x?` as meaning

```
match x {
    Err(e) => return Err(e),
    Ok(y) => y,
}
```

(see documentation [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/#the-question-mark-operator-))

What do you want to happen when `await` produces an error result? If you're not expecting an error to ever occur, then it should be safe to tell Rust to panic (i.e. crash) if it does. This is what `Result::unwrap` is for:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Started!");
    let body = reqwest::get("https://news.ycombinator.com")
        .await
        .unwrap()
        .text()
        .await
        .unwrap();

    println!("body = {:?}", body);
}
```

More likely, you should handle error results responsibly with some well defined behaviour. This could be attempting to recover (i.e. trying something different), or maybe logging an error message and exiting with a non-zero code if you're in the top-level `main` function. The simple way to do either of these would be to use a `match` statement yourself.

From this perspective, it becomes clear what the *intent* of the `?` operator is: it's a way of saying ***"It's not my responsibility to handle this error – it's the responsibility of the code that called me."*** The important thing here is that it still has to be *someone's* responsibility to decide how to handle errors.

Comment: Just a nit. Try to avoid unwrap() in prod code

Comment: How do I do it without unwrap then?

Comment: Use `match`! I've edited the answer to cover this option.