# Rust open image with other format than file extension

Tags: image, rust, image-formats

I am trying to open an image in my Rust program. The image is named foo.png, but it won't open the image with `image::open("foo.png")`.
If I rename the file to foo.jpeg, I can open the image, so my guess is that the formatting and the file extension do not match.

My question is then. how do I open a file named foo.png, but decode it as a jpeg?
I have tried `image::io::Reader`, but I can't seem to make it work properly.

Comment: You can check the first few bytes of the file for its [magic bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) then use the appropriate decoding function depending on the detected format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `image::load()` function, which lets you specify the format:

```rust
let image = image::load(BufReader::new(File::open("foo.png")?), ImageFormat::Jpeg)?;
```

Comment: If I do that I get the error "cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `()"



If I remove the "?" i get the error "the trait `Seek` is not implemented for `Result<File, std::io::Error>`"

Comment: "cannot use the ? operator in a function that returns ()" is another error, and if this part of Rust book - https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator - doesn't help you, it will possibly need another question (which is likely to be closed as duplicate, but I can't find proof for now).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58373663/cannot-use-the-operator-in-a-function-that-returns